# How can I disable/enable ubuntu's auto shut down feature?

Tags: temperature

Ubuntu has a feature of auto shutdown whenever it exceeds a temperature above 70 degrees Celsius. Is there any way to control this feature or prompt before the shut down?

Comment: I don't think this a feature of Ubuntu, but one of your chipset configured through BIOS, and you don't actually want to shut it off, because it saves your machine from heat death. What you may want, is a warning, when your system gets close to that threshold, so you can save your work and shut it down properly. You may also want to investigate methods, that keep you machine cool (remove dust, replace CPU thermal conductor, increase internal and/or external air flow, use more hardware acceleration).

Comment: I just want to be notified before the auto shut down so that i can save my work and shut down properly. Now I can see my system's core temperatures and other parametres using acpi -V command as answered by @UTF-8. Is there any script or tool that 'll prompt me as soon as the critical temperature is reached ?

Comment: That would be a different question. Please find a similar one or open your own. I also suggest, that you take a look at your BIOS configuration options. Many mainboards have BIOS features for thermal warnings and shutdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1710107&p=10579384#post10579384) is a resolution:

> Edit => /etc/default/grub
>
> Edit => GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
>
> Add => GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash thermal.nocrt=1"
>
> Update GRUB => sudo update-grub
>
> View settings, should be disabled => cat
>   /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THM/trip_points
>
> View temperature => acpi -V or sensors

However, doing this comes at an obvious risk, whereas getting rid of dust in your PC comes at a much lower risk. Plus, it can be that not Ubuntu but your bios shuts your PC down which means that Ubuntu is the wrong place to change settings.

Answer (score 1):

@UTF-8's answer doesn't work on ubuntu 20.04. Afer encountering the same problem I found the solution that works is to add `thermal.crt=190` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option in `/etc/default/grub.cfg`. setting the critical CPU temp to `190C` instead of the `100C` limit set by ubuntu.