# How to prevent Ubuntu 15.04 LiveCD from shutting down on critical temperature?

Tags: boot, 15.04, live-cd, overheating

A netbook I am trying to install Ubuntu to heats to 98°C and shuts down at the beginning of the installation process. There is also a BIOS auto-shutdown feature (non-customizable, shutting down at a temperature somewhat higher that only it itself knows) that makes me consider the 98°C OK as the BIOS does.

I have tried adding the `thermal.nocrt=1` parameter as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/605382/2390) suggests but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Almost 100°C seems definitely extremely hot and not healthy to your hardware components. Give it a good vacuuming and eliminate the reason why it heats up that strongly.

Comment: That's a well known software problem that applies to all EeePCs of that model under Linux.  @ByteCommander