# Disable thermal shutdown HP Pavilion 15

Tags: bios, hp-pavilion

My laptop keeps shutting down claiming that the processor has reached a temperature of 90 degrees. I don’t believe that this is the case: I’m 95% sure that there must be a faulty temperature sensor, since I’m almost certain that the processor is not reaching these temperatures. Sometimes the laptop will work fine for several hours before shutting down, but sometimes it will shut down within five minutes. I am only editing text files...

So, I know that this is probably a bad idea, but is it possible to disable thermal shutdown? I cannot find an option in Ubuntu or in BIOS (which I guess is the option I actually want).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/605382

Comment: Thanks, but I’m afraid it appears to be more of a BIOS issue.