# False overtemp error with ubuntu 20.04 on asus cpu dual boot with win10, win10 is fine

Tags: boot, hardware, overheating, temperature

I have an Asus tough gaming minitower system which I have been using for several years.

It's set up as dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and win10. win10 is working fine for hours and hours for years. Ubuntu was the same - but recently Ubuntu refuses to boot due to an over temp report from a cold CPU.

BIOS reports a constant CPU temp of 80C. That's incorrect. 80C is hot enough to scald skin and it feels cool to the touch. I just opened and cleaned everything and all radiator vanes and fans are clean and functioning. There is a blown temperature sensor.

Repairing the hardware is NOT an option at this time because I am in a remote location with no budget or access. I use this boot mode of advanced Computational Fluid Dynamics work and that's crucial to my getting the next contract which would pay to fix the hardware.

There is a "thermal.crt" setting in /etc/default/grub.cfg which can set the temperature higher

BUT!!!

That only works if I can boot Ubuntu long enough to edit the file, which is blocked by the bad temp sensor.

Is there any way to force a boot and ignore the temperature test?

Is there any way to edit grub.cfg from win10?

Are there any other hack arounds to get this system working without changing the hardware?

I request that Ubuntu add a

"Your CPU is over heating. Proceeding with startup could damage your system. Do you wish to proceed? Y/N"

question at start up. My computer works for me, is my property and my tool. If I wish to fry it, that is my right to choose - not the OS authors. I like linux because it doesn't try to be "Big Mama" and tell me what I have to do to make it happy. This forced safety measure with no override is counter to the linux design philosophy. Such and addition poses minimal risk - because MS Win10 is cruising along fat, dumb and happy - never even reading the sensor.

I have other, unpleasant, fixes like using linux on windows or making a laptop dual boot - I would prefer not to use those due to time and performance. The software I'm using is OpenGL and won't work properly in a VM.

Comment: Instead of struggling to edit the file from Windows, have you tried temporarily applying the setting from GRUB? I assume the temperature sensor is active in Linux and not GRUB. You can press escape on boot to get the GRUB menu, then press e with Ubuntu selected, then add the `thermal.crt` there for 1 boot only. If that doesn't work, someone can post an answer involving some Win10 program or a customized LiveCD.

Comment: Thanks 

Not familiar with the boot process or GRUB. This is probably what I've been looking for.

I think it's also possible to install a LSW with ubuntu under windows. Launch a command line window under that, and edit the file from there. That's a lot of work for changing one number.

I'll look into your approach and let you know what happens.

Comment: No, if you installed a LSW it would be a different "computer." It would be like if you had two hard drives and installed 1 copy of Windows on each. Even though it's the same CPU, editing a file location in one installation doesn't change the file in the other one.

Comment: Thanks, I've been wrapped up with other work and haven't got back to this yet.

Yes, they are separate boots on separate disks, but each boot should be able to see the other disk. Just don't edit THIS boot disk and edit the OTHER boot disk.

Comment: Just follow https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/1004020 except with `thermal.crt`

Comment: Finally back on this and now it needs to be done.

Found this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/605378/how-can-i-disable-enable-ubuntus-auto-shut-down-feature

Added " thermal.nocrt=1" in grub as instructed - no effect.

The system is fine except for a blown temperature sensor.
I'm located in a very, very remote area with no service options.
The system runs fine, 24/7 under Win10.
It's an overly protective option in Ubuntu that makes it impossible to use Ubuntu.